# Jqplot doesn't support showGridLine for y(n)axis, while n> 2, does it?

Tags: jqplot

I used jqplot for my line chart, and maybe I will use more yaxis. So, with yaxis and y2axis
the horizontal grid line display well on the chart. But there's no horizontal grid line if I use y3axis or y4axis. 
I guessed maybe jqplot doesn't support to do this, or maybe it's a bug.

Take a look here:

> 

```
var tfsGraphNodes= [[1,4],[2,2],[3,21],[4,61],[5,71],[6,10]];

jQuery.jqplot('chart1', [tfsGraphNodes], {
 title: 'Applicant Behaviour', 
    series: [{color: 'green',label: 'Applicant Trend', yaxis: "y4axis"}],   
 legend: {show: true}, 
 highlighter: {showTooltip: true}, 
 axes: {
  xaxis: {
   tickOptions: {formatString: '%d'},
   //Comment or un-comment to see what happens on xaxis's ticks
   tickInterval: 1
  },

     y4axis: {
         tickOptions: {
             showGridline: true
         }
     }
 }
});
```

my current jqplot version is: 2007.04.27

So, could you please tell me the way to deal with this? I'm appreciate any solution

Comment: Hi guys, is there any one support to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, no one get the same problem like me before, so I solved it by myself. The current jqplot didn't support to do that, so to make it work, we need to modify the js source of jqplot.

In jqplot source. We will see some place define y(n)axis, we just add the number yaxis we want there and modify the loop for suitable. I did that and it's worked fine for me.